# Unable to use SSIS's SSDT in VS2010 / SQL Server2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a full version of SqlServer 2012 installed on my local machine and have installed SSDT from the installation package (and updates)

I've then opened the SSDT visual studio application and installed the SSDT package from Microsoft which appears to have worked correctly.

However, when I attempt to start an Integration Services project I get the following error message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document: To design
>   Integration Services packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). SSDT
>   has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2012:
>   Standard. Enterprise. Developer, or Evaluation. To install SSDT, run
>   SQL Server Setup and select SQL Server Data Tools.

**Notes:**

- When I run the SQL2012
  installer, it says SSDT is installed
  already.
- Other topics via gogole / stack overflow have mentioned this
  may happen with 2008 compatifility, or when express versions had
  previously been installed.
- I'm working on a fresh installation of
  Windows 7 and with no express products installed.
- I've uninstalled everything and reinstalled twice already.

**Edit: added screenshots**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Edit 2: added About text**

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel Microsoft
>   .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709 SP1Rel
>
> Installed Version: SSDS Standard
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   01011-532-2002361-70450 Microsoft Visual
>   Basic 2010
>
> Microsoft Visual C# 2010   01011-532-2002361-70450 Microsoft Visual C#
>   2010
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 3.0
>   01011-532-2002361-70450 Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications
>   3.0
>
> Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010   01011-532-2002361-70450
>   Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010
>
> AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio   2.4.11610.27 AnkhSVN
>   - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.4.11610.27   * Ankh.Package 2.4.11610.27  * Subversion 1.7.6 via SharpSvn 1.7006.2206.13750
>
> SharpSvn is linked to: Apr 1.4.6, Apr-util 1.4.2, Cyrus Sasl 2.1.23,
>   Neon 0.29.6, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012, serf 1.1.0, SQLite 3.7.12.1,
>   Subversion 1.7.6-SharpSvn-1.7.6, ZLib 1.2.7 SharpSvn is optionally
>   linked to: Berkeley DB 4.4.20, SharpPlink 1.7006.2206.13750
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services    Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services
>   Designer  Version 11.0.3000.0
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   10.3.21208.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
>   Services Designer Version 11.0.2100.60
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services    Microsoft SQL Server Reporting
>   Services Designers  Version 11.0.3000.0
>
> Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509) 
>   KB983509 This service pack is for Visual Studio 2010 Shell
>   (Integrated) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack,
>   this service pack will be uninstalled automatically. For more
>   information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you installing? You mention using the express installer. You cannot use Integration Services with the express edition.

Comment: Sorry, thats a Typo. Its a full server installation. Corrected.

Comment: Just for kicks and grins, in the Visual Studio About menu above, click on `SQL Server Integration Services` What's reported there?

Comment: Product Details: Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 11.0.2100.60 
Added full details above in edit #2

Comment: I was hoping to see that you were bitten by the SSDT (data tools) is not SSDT-BI (SS*S) product naming fiasco. What version of SQL Server do you have installed? Developer?

Comment: In the update you've provided SQL Server 2012 is not mentioned. Do you have SQL Server DB Engine installed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Business Intelligence Data Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=36843)