# Get an error creating a SSIS project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

Im getting an error when try to create a SSIS project to develop a simple DTS on VS 2010 sp1

This is error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document: To design
>   Integration Services packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). SSDT
>   has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2012:
>   Standard. Enterprise. Developer, or Evaluation. To install SSDT, run
>   SQL Server Setup and select SQL Server Data Tools.

i have same problem describe on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199303/unable-to-use-ssiss-ssdt-in-vs2010-sql-server2012) and neither here neither on Google i found a solution.

Want link also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gFEDYzjpas) with what i would like to do.

Programs installed:

> Vs 2010 pro sp1
>
> Vs 2012 shell
>
> Sql server 2008 r2
>
> Sql server 2012
>
> SSdata tools 2010 and 2012

i think that i need of SSIS-BIDS on vs2010

Note:
With vs2012 shell i can create a new ssis project but on vs2010 sp1 no

Comment: You cannot.  Even though you can install SSDT for Visual Studio 2010, you cannot actually use Visual Studio 2010 for any BIDS functionality.  You must use either 2008 or 2012.

Comment: Why on video linked in my post isnt it? he open vs 2010 shell and create a ssis project!

Comment: I haven't the foggiest.  But I have spent hours and hours trying to get this to work in the past (and downloaded some more stuff today to try again) and it does not work.  That video was the first time I have ever seen that it might be possible.  I would certainly be interested in the how if you can get it to work.

Comment: for sure! im contacting video owner to get some explanations